# regex select all number after a string

Tags: regex, string, numbers, match

I'm new to regex and i want to know if there is anyway to select all numbers after a matched string?

For example:

Input:

`important string
abc 100
def 50
ghi jk 10
m 60
not important string
aa 90
bb 20`

And as output, i want to select all these numbers: 100, 50, 10, 60

I have tried with `important string[\w\n ]* (\d+)` but i got only 60

Thanks alot!

Comment: Judging by your input, you may just use `/\d+/g`. You may check if a string contains `important string` with your programming language means. What is the programming language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yea.. but the problem is this input was in another big text, which has a lot of numbers too, and /\d+/g will take all of them. And by the way i used regex101.com to practice, so i didn't really use any programming language

Comment: Then there are still 2 questions: 1) what regex flavor will you be using? (Regex101 has 3 to offer); 2) what is the trailing boundary (when to stop collecting the numbers after *important string*)?

Comment: Something like https://regex101.com/r/Ajaamu/2 might help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah that's what i'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic PCRE approach to matching multiple occurrences in between some texts is to use a `\G` based pattern that allows anchoring matches at the end of the previous successful match:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<!\bnot )important string)(?:(?!not important string)\D)*?\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ajaamu/3)

Basically,

```
(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|STARTING_DELIMITER_STRING)(?:(?!END_DELIMITER_STRING).)*?\K\d+
```

Or, in order to stay within the initial `STARTING_DELIMITER_STRING` boundaries, add it to the negative lookahead:

```
(?s)(?:\G(?!\A)|STARTING_DELIMITER_STRING)(?:(?!STARTING_DELIMITER_STRING|END_DELIMITER_STRING).)*?\K\d+
```

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|(?<!\bnot )important string)` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or an `important string` literal char sequence not preceded with `not` + space
- `(?:(?!not important string)\D)*?` - any char other than digit (`\D`), 0+ occurrences, as few as possible, that is not a starting point for a `not important string` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+` - 1+ digits